# Wordpress create widget area in a widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am trying to insert a custom widget area in another widget, but don't know where to start. Do I need to register new widget areas in widget class constructor with unique id's ?

What I am trying to achieve:
Insert a section widget which contains a widget area.
Insert custom widgets into that section with the widget area.

```
<?php
    function dov_load_widget_default( ) {
            register_widget( 'section' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'dov_load_widget_default' );

    class section extends WP_Widget {
            function __construct( ) {
                    parent::__construct(
                            'section',
                            __( 'Portfolio sections', 'dov_portfolio' ),
                            array( 'description' => __( 'Default section for widgets', 'dov_portfolio' ) )
                    );
            }

            // Creating widget front-end
            public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

            }

            // Widget Backend
            public function form( $instance ) {

            }

            // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
            public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
                    $instance = array( );
                    return $instance;
            }
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the right way but it seems to work.

```
    function dov_load_sidebars( ) {
            register_sidebar( array(
                    'id'   => 'portfolio_sections',
                    'name' => __( 'Portfolio sections', 'dov_portfolio' )
            ));

            $sections = wp_get_sidebars_widgets( );
            if( isset( $sections[ 'portfolio_sections' ] ) ) :
                    $sections = $sections[ 'portfolio_sections' ];
                    foreach( $sections as $section ) :
                            register_sidebar( array(
                                    'id' => $section,
                                    'name' => __( 'Portfolio section', 'dov_portfolio' ) . ': ' . $section
                            ));
                    endforeach;
            endif;
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'dov_load_sidebars' );
```

EDIT: After inserting the section widget the widget areas don't refresh. How can I refresh them or should I add them using js ?